# Package not found in jsp

Tags: eclipse, jsp

i have added new project in my workspace which is having 2 projects `A` and `B` respectively. now i have added third project `C` in build path as well as in project reference of `A`. i am using some `package` `c.foo.*` of `C` in  Project `A`'s `test.jsp` but while importing `c.foo.*` package i am getting error as Package not found. how i can access package `c.foo.*` of Project `C` in `test.jsp` of Project `A` ? i am using eclipse IDE

Comment: Please post examples of your JSP

Answer (score 0):

A `Page not found` error means entirely different: the request URL is plain wrong. If the import has actually failed, you would have gotten a compilation error. Are you sure that the URL is correct?

That said, raw Java code doesn't belong in JSP files. Use a Servlet for this. You can use `doGet()` to preprocess requests and `doPost()` to postprocess requests. In a Servlet class you can just import/write Java code the usual way without struggling with *scriptlets*.

Answer (score 0):

Are the source folders in project C exported from that project's Java Build Path properties?